# How to update My Places on Google Earth with kmz files from my computer every week using Python

Tags: python, google-earth

I am very new to programming and am having problems creating a Python script that will first loop through a folder to select all the .kmz files and see if there are new ones in the folder, then take the .kmz files and load them onto Google Earth's My Places once a week creating a dynamic map.  So far all I have been been able to do is the first part that loops through and prints out the files in the folder. Please note I am using Python 2.6.   Any assistance with the rest of the python script would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Current code:

```
import os

path = "//ax1gis03/f$/arcgisserver/arcgiskml/"
listing = os.listdir(path)

for infile in listing:
  print "current file is:" + infile

#After looping is done...
kml_BottomPart = "</Folder></Document></kml>"
finalKML = kml_TopPart + networklinkKML + kml_BottomPart
print finalKML
```

Comment: Could you please include the code you already wrote? Thanks

Comment: Sure.  Right now the code I have looks like this:
import os

path = "//ax1gis03/f$/arcgisserver/arcgiskml/"

listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    print "current file is:" + infile


#After looping is done...
kml_BottomPart = "</Folder></Document></kml>"

finalKML = kml_TopPart + networklinkKML + kml_BottomPart

print finalKML